# How to Rate Limit for Mobility Solution?

Tags: rest, api, httprequest, iot

I feel that, IP based rate limit (API request thersold per second /minute) is not the reliable solution for Mobile IOT projects as many users use the same IP address to connect to API server. Please advise the best approach and Pros & Cons

Comment: Would user level rate limiting help?

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing that device Id level or API token based rate limit. But, just looking the expert opinion.